# Allocating memory for unions and difference between union pointer and union of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, casting, unions

Since my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235444/struct-pointer-casts#comment85484251_49237262) couldn't be confidently answered, I ask here again in hope that someone knows for sure:

1. Is there any difference (besides syntactical) between a pointer to a union and a union that contains pointers to its elements? The generated assembly in [this](https://godbolt.org/g/m6MbUp) example is identical.
2. As long as I'm never accessing the other members, is it allowed to allocate memory for only one of the members (which isn't the largest)?

Regarding the 2nd question, 6.5.2.1 of the C89 draft says:

> The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members - The value of-at most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time. A pointer to a union object suitably converted points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit-field. then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa.

So, at least when properly cast, it should be fine to only allocate space for one of the members, but I couldn't find anything that guarantees that only the corresponding bits of the accessed member are used when using a union.

EDIT:

Given the following definitions:

```
typedef struct s1
{
    int a;
} s1;

typedef struct s2
{
    int a;
    int b;
} s2;

union u1
{
    s1 a;
    s2 b;
};
```

Is this legal:

```
union u1 *u = malloc(sizeof(s1));
u->a.a = 3;
printf("s1.a=%d\n", u->a.a);
printf("s2.a=%d\n", u->b.a);
```

Comment: I updated with some code that I think reflects what you're asking, based on your earlier question.  Feel free to update if my assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: "Is there any difference (besides syntactical) between a pointer to a union and a union that contains pointers to its elements?"

Yeah, the latter does not make sense. A union cannot contain a pointer to its elements, because that pointer would be the element itself. It is kind of the same nonsense as if saying "I want to build my house, and at the same time I want my house to be a road sign pointing at my house". So I make no sense of the question - what is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Why would you want to allocate only enough for a smaller member?  It would seem that, if that's what you want to do, a union isn't the object you're looking for anyway.  Just allocate an instance of the smaller structure.  Secondly, given the typical use cases for unions, I think members which are pointers to other members is risky.  That is, unless each "top-level" object has pointers in the same location, but still ... .

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @AndrewFalanga The answer to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235444/struct-pointer-casts) was to use unions. If I allocated enough space for both, the singly linked list would be pretty useless.

Comment: Marc: The standard does *not* allow you to allocate less space than would be needed by the union's largest member. You may be able to get away with it, but it will not be fully-conformant code. Unions (like structs, and unlike arrays) can be used as single objects, so `union Funion a, *b; b = malloc(sizeof Small); a.small.field1 = 1; *b = a;` will overrun memory. You could argue that you never do that and copying `a` field by field will work; probably it will, but afaik the standard doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: @rici What if I had a union that contains 2 pointers to different structs that share a common inital sequence? I allocate space for either of them and only access the common members. Or would it be UB to access the members via another struct than the one that was allocated?[Here's](https://godbolt.org/g/96CnA1) an example of what I mean.

Comment: @mark: i think it is safe, but it is not guaranteed either. The union isn't doing anything for you here, though. In your first example, the `union` enables the common prefix rule, but in the case of a union of pointers, that rule doesn't apply. Technically. Of course, real world compilers are less demanding about common prefixes, and I think you're fine without the union.

Comment: These are basically the games Posix had to play to get `sockaddr` to work. It does work (on Posix-compliant implementations, at least) but it's a massive kludge which confuses the hell out of programmers just learning socket programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the pointer-to-union thing.

Using a part of your example code (which you should really have in the question body)

```
union u1
{
    s1 a;
    s2 b;
};
```

Then if you have

```
union u1 my_union;
```

you are guaranteed that `&my_union` is equal to e.g. `&my_union.a` *and* `&my_union.b`.

---

Regarding

```
union u1 *u = malloc(sizeof(s1));
u->a.a = 3;
printf("s1.a=%d\n", u->a.a);
printf("s2.a=%d\n", u->b.a);
```

This only works because of two reasons: Type-punning is allowed using unions, and both `u->a.a` and `u->b.a` are the exact same size and at the exact same position. The way I see it is that technically it's UB but works because of other requirements.

If you attempted to access `u->b.b` the UB would be guaranteed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this answers either of my questions. Also, this seems to disagree one with the part "A pointer to a union object suitably converted", which suggests that &my_union need to be cast to s1* or s2* to actually work.

Comment: @MarcSchulze The casting *is* the "suitable converted" thing. With the first section I just say that the addresses are guaranteed to be equal, which is why the conversion (casting) is guaranteed to work.