# C freeing a string inside a Union

Tags: c, memory, malloc, union, free

So say I have a Union

```
typedef union Union{
int firstField;
char * secondField;
}Union;
```

and I allocate this union on the heap and allocate secondField on the heap. How do I free the secondField?

Comment: What were the errors when you tried to `free` it?

Comment: I sometimes get exit code 3 and other times the program just hangs and crashes. I suspect I am getting an access violation error. Someone on another post said this may be undefined behavious as the union doesnt know that im actually trying to free the char pointer?

Comment: There is nothing inherently special about a pointer that is a member of a union.  If it is the member currently stored in the union and its value is a  valid pointer then you free the memory it points to by passing the pointer to `free()`.  If that doesn't seem to be working for you then we'll probably need to see a [mre] to understand the nature of the problem.

Comment: does this help?(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259777/allocating-memory-for-unions-and-difference-between-union-pointer-and-union-of-p)

Comment: The problem with unions is that after creation you have no means of telling whether you are dealing with a union that uses `firstField` or `secondField`. In my daily work I deal with this by declaring an enum with an entry for every possible union member. Then I combine the enum and the union in a struct. I initialize the enum along with the union member. So when I'm freeing I can check if the union actually contains a pointer or just an int that does not need to be freed. Usually I also write functions for member access with asserts that tell me when I'm trying to access the wrong member.

Answer (score 2):

Just in the obvious way:

```
Union *up;
up = malloc(sizeof(Union));
up->secondField  = malloc(n);
// ...
free(up->secondField);
free(up);
```

Of course, you must not assign to `up->firstField` in between the assignment and `free` of `up->secondField`.  So you have to design your code to ensure that this cannot happen.